# Swapping JButtons/JLables in Java application

Tags: java, sorting, jbutton, swap, simulator

I am designing a *sorting algorithm simulator* in java language.when i design that i faced **swapping buttons** problem. actually they didn't move or change their current place at all.

here is my code :

```java
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class mainGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable{

        Thread a;

        JButton[] num_array;
        int []arr;
        int Swap;

        public mainGUI() {
            initComponents();

            a = new Thread(this);
        }
        private void sortBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

            arr = new int[6];

            if (num1.getText().isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't leave this field empty");
                num1.grabFocus();
            }
            else if(num2.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't leave this field empty");
                num2.grabFocus();
            }
            else if(num3.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't leave this field empty");
                num3.grabFocus();
            }
            else if(num4.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't leave this field empty");
                num4.grabFocus();
            }
            else if(num5.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't leave this field empty");
                num5.grabFocus();
            }
            else if (num6.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Can't leave this field empty");
                num6.grabFocus();
            }
            else
            {
                arr[0] = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
                arr[1] = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());
                arr[2] = Integer.parseInt(num3.getText());
                arr[3] = Integer.parseInt(num4.getText());
                arr[4] = Integer.parseInt(num5.getText());
                arr[5] = Integer.parseInt(num6.getText());

                numB1.setText(num1.getText());
                numB2.setText(num2.getText());
                numB3.setText(num3.getText());
                numB4.setText(num4.getText());
                numB5.setText(num5.getText());
                numB6.setText(num6.getText());

                num_array = new JButton[]{numB1,numB2,numB3,numB4,numB5,numB6};        
                Swap = 1;
                a.start();
            }
        }                                       
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override

            public void run() {
                new mainGUI().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
    @Override

    public void run() {



        if (Swap == 1)
        {
            int i,j,key;

            for(i = 1;i<arr.length;i++)

            {
                key = arr[1];
                j = 1;

                while (j>0 && arr[j -1] > key)
                {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                    j--;

                    try {

                        swap2(j,j + 1);
                        keyprinting(key);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Error Occured !.Please Try again.!");
                    }

                }
                arr[j] = key;
            }

        }

        //a.start(); //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    private void swap2(int n1, int n2) throws InterruptedException{

        for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
        {
            num_array[n1].setLocation(num_array[n1].getLocation().x,num_array[n1].getLocation().y);
            num_array[n2].setLocation(num_array[n2].getLocation().x,num_array[n2].getLocation().y);

        }
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    private void keyprinting(int key) {
        System.out.println(key);

    }
}
```

Comment: This subject is popular today : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303619/how-to-move-a-button-slowly-from-one-location-to-another-in-java/39304195?noredirect=1#comment65942257_39304195

Comment: Consider an [MCVE]  to focus on the specific problem