# How to move a button slowly from one location to another in Java?

Tags: java

I have two buttons and I want to set the 1 button where the 2 button was and vise versa. But I want it to slowly move from the first place to the other. Anyone have an idea how to do it?

```
int num_1_x= num_array[num1].getLocation().x;
int num_2_x =num_array[num2].getLocation().x;

num_array[num1].setLocation(num_2_x, num_array[num1].getLocation().y); 
num_array[num2].setLocation(num_1_x,num_array[num2].getLocation().y);
```

Answer (score 1):

That very much depends on how your current **layout** is organized. You see, normally buttons would be placed in some panel, using a layout manager. The only thing you can do there ... would be swapping their locations; and that would be like "instantly".

But if you would be doing "hardcoded" location setting; so button1 is at x1, y1; and button2 is at x2, y2; then of course you could calculate the "geographic" distance between the two buttons; slice that distance into a number of sections; and then re-position both buttons in several steps. In other words: you would let them "wander" over the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it is best to break a "big problem" into smaller ones, and take it one step at a time. 
I would suggest to start with learning the following DRAGGING example :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class DragTest extends JFrame {

    int pX, pY;

    public DragTest() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));

        JPanel  jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        add(jPanel1);

        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        final JButton button = new JButton("Drag Me");
        button.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 25);

        button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                button.setLocation((button.getLocation().x + me.getX()) - pX,
                        (button.getLocation().y + me.getY()) - pY);
                jPanel1.revalidate();
                jPanel1.repaint();
            }
        });
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                // Get x,y and store them
                pX = me.getX();
                pY = me.getY();
            }
        });

        jPanel1.add(button);
        jPanel1.revalidate();
        jPanel1.repaint();

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DragTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Next, when you get the idea, try to change pX and pY grammatically rather than by mouse drag (to create the desired animation).

Than do it with two buttons. 

As a last step add the calculation required to swap positions.